# How do I completely turn off the Chrome notifications on my MacBook?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I am using MacOSX 10.14.6 now.

I really hate the Chrome notifications sent by the websites, not only those I visited only 1 time but also those big websites like Facebook or Yahoo.

I just want to get back to days when Chrome doesn't even have this feature.

I tried to turn it off in the chrome://settings/content/notifications

but it's not working. The notifications are still poping out.

How do I totally disable this feature on system level? Doe MacOS have this ability to do so?

Comment: What kinds of notifications are you getting? Add at least one example of the text in the notification(s).

Comment: If chrome is still sending you notifications, I wonder if it could be an extension that's getting past your global notification settings.